# Error creating LINQ query against Azure Table Storage

Tags: linq, .net-core, azure-table-storage

I am accessing a table storage from a .NET CORE 3.1 console app

I am using latest (at this time) PM

microsoft.azure.cosmos.table\1.0.8\

which in turn uses

Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core\2.11.2

Many operations on the table work fine but I encountered an error while creating a LINQ query

This is the line generating the error, a **null reference exception**

> ```
>      var myquery = new TableQuery<DocEntity>()
>         .Where(r => r.PartitionKey == "doc_manager_test_client");
> ```

and this is the workaround that solves the problem and allow me to execute the query

But I don't like this syntax, ugly and verbose, makes long queries unreadable

> ```
>      var myquery = new TableQuery<DocEntity>()
>         .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "doc_manager_test_client"));
> ```

I don't think the problem lies in DocEntity , anyway this is the class

> ```
>   public class DocEntity : TableEntity {
>      public DocEntity() {
>      }
>
>      public DocEntity(string doc_manager_id, string doc_id) {
>         PartitionKey = doc_manager_id;
>         RowKey = doc_id;
>      }
>
>      public string DocName { get; set; }
>      public string DocCategory { get; set; }
>      public Int64 DocSize { get; set; }
>   }
> ```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

The official doc is poor, I didn't find any complete sample that shows how to do LINQ query, there is just a snippet like mine above that doesn't work in my app. Maybe it's a versioning problem, they used previous versions of .NET, but I want it to work with core 3.1

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue. The issue is coming because `Provider` property of `TableQuery` is null (not sure why).

Here's the workaround that you can use:

```
        StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials("<account-name>", "<account-key>");
        CloudTable table = new CloudTable(new Uri("https://<account-name>.table.core.windows.net/<table-name>"),
            credentials);
        var tableQuery = table.CreateQuery<DocEntity>().Where(r => r.PartitionKey == "somevalue");
```

and you should not get the error.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the query needs to know which table refer to (not just the entity) even in creation phase and it's taking that info when you call the createquery method of the table. I was using the table method with executequery thinking this would be the place where you need to provide the table reference but I was wrong.